# Does BET theory apply to type H3 and H4 isotherm for calculating surface area?

Tags: surface-chemistry

[image: type H3 and H4 are classification of IUPAC for hysteresis loops]

BET applies to type 2 and 4. That is basically unanimous.

Comment: You should elaborate and put some links.

Comment: This is enough.If you know the field, you will know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample that shows loop of H3 type have **(very likely) no** micropores (small uptake in low p/p0 range). In this case you can apply BET theory in common p/p0 range (0.05-0.3). The sample that shows H4 hysteresis **have** micropores (large uptake in low p/p0 range). The BET theory can be applied here, but in a much lower p/p0 range. For activated carbon, for example, one would look for a linear(!) range between p/p0 = 0.02-0.1. Generally, the BET theory is not suitable for microporous materials.